# Runtime error 'Firebase Firestore' Undefined class in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**I am trying to use cloud_firestore: ^3.1.8 it show me a run time error and I try to decrease the version but doesn't work**

= my sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"

[error in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JXPO.png)

[I imported library in my pubspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLq1K.png)

Comment: Try with remove the version of `cloud_firestore` library. like `cloud_firestore: `

Comment: it still, give me an error

Comment: Try reloading VSCode window.

Answer (score 0):

I solve This issue using this version cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4